# What or Who is a Brahman?

Tags: brahman, knowledge

From the link https://vedicheritage.gov.in/brahmanas/ I seems to understand that the term **Brahmana** relates to knowledgeable information aka the vedas

- that described certain ways,processes,of coexisting on this planet,
- presented in written or oral form.

However it seems over time people who were capable of reading and understanding this knowledge text (noun) of **vedas**,
then came to be known as **Brahman** (personal noun).
*[just like Google(noun) is used as a verb (meaning 'to search') in today's times]*

And that all were not capable then to read, speak, write, efficiently in those days since each were identified by their innate capabilities and required to perform specialised tasks as per that.

Can someone please explain whether this labeling of humans of a certain "hindu sect" as *Brahmans* really makes sense in today's time of knowledge which is now open to all

- **Vedic knowledge** if decoded and made available to all may so to say, enable "even morons turn smart"?

hope to read experts comments for self learning!

Would debunk this 'Brahmin superiority' bashing trend if origin basics are understood well by all.

Comment: Brahman is a Upanishadic concept. Bramhin is a one who knows and realises Brahman

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru bramhin is nothing it is written as brAhmana

Comment: Vedic study demands a spirit of piety righteousness , confirmity to austerities, (which cannot be imposed on a large population),  unlike modern education, which has no such prerequisites,also  a means for earning money, where certain skills and techniques are taught and mastered. Purport of vedic education is different. Veda mantras are so subtle, and should only be learnt thru Guru..,only then the recitation of mantra would  fructify. 
Learning english translations on vedanta,  Vedas etc.can be done by anyone but it is not same as undertaking a  study of Vedas in Patashala.

Comment: Hello & welcome to HSE.  Please re-read your post and edit to clarify when you mean Brahman & when you mean Brahmin. As of now the question is unclear.